# Can you update HP firmware via iLO virtual disk?

Tags: ilo

Simple question - can you do this? Right now we have a server in a remote data center with no ability to get anyone on site. We recently had a HP tech there to swap out a failed disk, however the disk is now refusing to rebuild. Apparently there may be some issues with the firmware rev, but there's no way we can get a DVD out there in a timeframe we're comfortable with. I do have the DVD firmware-update iso though, and I'm staring at the remote console just wondering.

Obviously I won't be updating iLO, but the other firmware.

Comment: So have you tried it yet? :)

Comment: Not yet, we managed to get remote hands on. After completely powering down the server and booting it back up, the controller is now showing that there are 0 drives and 0 logical disks

Comment: No drives, huh? I think you need to find that HP tech and beat him into submission.

Comment: What OS is being used?

Comment: RHEL 5 - it's looking like we received a bunk replacement disk, and immediately after a disk on another RAID failed on the same server. Birds of a feather I guess :( Looks like the controller couldn't handle it all at once. After a cold boot the disks are at least showing up again.

Answer (score 3):

Barring firmware bugs that actually prevent booting from virtual media (e.g. some old G5/G6 systems had a problem where they would not boot from virtual media if there were external USB devices connected) you should be fine to boot from a virtual DVD and update your firmware.

Comment: Ok great - my biggest concern was if it tried to update iLO firmware while there was a virtual disk attached. I wasn't sure if the other firmware updates may have modules that could mess with it

Comment: No, it's even safe to update the iLO firmware; you'll merely be disconnected from the remote console and have to reconnect. See the HP Smart Update Firmware DVD User Guide.

Answer (score 2):

> can you do this?

Yes. Though it's going to be slow as ****.

Comment: Still a heck of a lot faster than me driving from Philadelphia to Chicago :)